# Who is the Umpire in this picture?

Tags: dc, character-identification

The ["Go-karting with Bowser" page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoKartingWithBowser) on TVTropes shows a picture of Superman pitching a baseball with Joker at bat, Batman behind him as catcher, and a fourth person behind Batman wearing an Uncle Sam getup as well as an umpire's mask- does anyone know who the umpire could be?

[image: an unexpected baseball team]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The character is [Uncle Sam](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Uncle_Sam_(New_Earth))

> Uncle Sam is described as a spiritual entity created through an occult
>   ritual by the Founding Fathers of the United States. This "Spirit of
>   America" was initially bound to a powerful talisman and would take
>   physical form by merging with a dying patriot. The Spirit of America
>   had taken human form as the Minute-Man during the Revolutionary War,
>   Brother Jonathan in later conflicts and, during the American Civil
>   War, had been split in two as Johnny Reb and Billy Yank.

The comic panel is from [DC Superstars #10](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Super-Stars_Vol_1_10) which features a baseball game between some of the greatest heroes and greatest villains in DC history. Sam is drafted in as a neutral observer, one with impeccable credentials as a judge and an encyclopaedic knowledge of baseball rules.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did the New York DA dislike Uncle Sam?

Comment: @JAB - Silver Ghost set them up. He took control of (some of) their bodies in Freedom Fighters Vol 1. #2 and the DA tried to arrest them. They resisted and spent the next 10 issues on the run from the police.